# Spinning globe GIF with cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy, matplotlib-animation

I'm failing to find the most efficient way to generate a simple animation of a spinning globe with a filled contour using cartopy. The following code yields a static gif, probably because the figure is not redrawing itself? Is there a way for the animation function to just change the geographic projection, without calling a `contourf()` again (which is computationally expensive)?

```py
from pylab import *
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

lon, lat = meshgrid(
    (linspace(-180,180,361)+0.5)[::4],
    (linspace(-90,90,181)+0.5)[::4],
    )   

h = (abs(lon)<20).astype(int) * (abs(lat)<10).astype(int)

fig = figure(figsize=(3,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Orthographic())
ax.contourf(lon, lat, h, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

def update_fig(t):
    ax.projection = ccrs.Orthographic(t)

ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    update_fig,
    frames = linspace(0,360,13)[:-1],
    interval = 100,
    blit = False,
    )

ani.save('mwe.gif')
```

Comment: Unfortunately no there isn’t :/ to do this you’d need to be using a web-based projection framework, not gdal, which cartopy uses to manage projections

Comment: That said, you should be able to completely redraw the figure in each frame and create the gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting that your code does not actually produce a static gif. If you add borders to your axis (with `ax.coastlines()`) then you'll see that the globe is being updated each frame, your data is just not updating to match the new projection.

This problem can be solved if you're using `ax.pcolormesh()` as follows:

```
from pylab import *
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

lon, lat = meshgrid(
    (linspace(-180,180,361)+0.5)[::4],
    (linspace(-90,90,181)+0.5)[::4],
    )   

h = (abs(lon)<20).astype(int) * (abs(lat)<10).astype(int)

fig = figure(figsize=(3,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Orthographic())
ax.coastlines()
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, h, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

def update_fig(t):
    ax.projection = ccrs.Orthographic(t)
    mesh.set(transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    update_fig,
    frames = linspace(0,360,13)[:-1],
    interval = 200)
```

Unfortunately, the object produced by `ax.contourf` doesn't seem to work in this way. The closest I could find was `mesh.set_array()`, which is used in the [cartopy documentation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/miscellanea/animate_surface.html#sphx-glr-gallery-miscellanea-animate-surface-py) for `pcolormesh` but also works for `contourf`. There is no `.set_transform()` or `.set()` for the object produced by `contourf`.